# Macro - Copy all from sheet 1 Column A to everything in sheet 2 column A and insert into sheet 3 colums a and b

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking for a macro which will allow me to copy everything from sheet 1 column A against everything in sheet 2 column A and then insert them into sheet 3 as columns A and B.

I'll demonstrate what I'm looking for.

```
Sheet 1
A        
------
Ben               
Jerry             
Steve   


Sheet 2
A       
------
Code A           
Code B           
Code C
```

Once macro is ran the Outcome results should look like:

```
Sheet 3
A       | B       
--------+---------
ben     |Code A    
ben     |Code B    
ben     |Code C    
steve   |Code A    
steve   |Code B    
steve   |Code C        
jerry   |Code A    
jerry   |Code B    
jerry   |Code C
```

The following is what I have attempted with

```
Sub TransferData()

'Transfer data
Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1:A4").Copy Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(1, "A")

'Transfer data
Sheets("sheet2").Range("A1:A4").Copy Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(1, "B")
End Sub
```

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. Have you tried recording a macro?

Comment: I have attempted a macro myself however I've only gotten as far as insert all from sheets 1 and 2 into sheet 3 against cell 1 from sheet 1 and cell 1 in sheet 2,

I have edited the question with a sample of what I have attempted with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, Updated code:

```
Sub TransferData()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set ws3 = Sheets("Sheet3")

    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    For i = 1 To ws1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For j = 1 To ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            ws3.Range("A" & (ws3.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1)) = _
                ws1.Range("A" & i)
            ws3.Range("B" & (ws3.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1)) = _
                ws2.Range("A" & j)
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I should have been more clearer my apologies. I need everything in sheet 2 to go into column B.

Similar to the sample I provided in the question. Except I'm not sure on how to go about getting the macro insert all from sheet 1 and sheet 2 where sheet 3 will should have multiple instances of sheet 1 and 2 data in the same manner as the demonstration in the question.

Comment: Take from sheet2 column A and output to sheet3 Column B

Comment: Thanks for your attempt @mehow, comes back with the same results the one I provided in the question.

Needs to have as an example sheet 1 cell 1 and every cell in column a on sheet 2 and insert that into each cell on sheet 3, in column a and b respectively.

So you'd have in sheet 3 Ben in column a, cell 1, cell 2, cell 3, and then in column B you'd have code a in cell 1, code b in cell 2 etc

Comment: @Moulton glad I could help. Here on stackoverflow, we say thank you by accepting and upvoting answers that helped us :)

Comment: Again thanks for the help, sadly unable to upvote due to my rep. I'll keep playing around with VBA until I can get the desired results.

Comment: @Moulton just edit your original question and post how the results should be. Youve been unclear so its hard for me to guess what your results should look like. maybe do a sample screenshot that would help probably

Comment: I have updated the question using a more understandable format, apologies if I wasn't as clear the first time, hope the updated question is more clear.

Comment: That's perfect thanks, I have accepted, I will come back to this page at a later date to upvote once I have the ability to do so.

Really appreciate the help many thanks mehow.

Comment: @Moulton no problem. Try to be clearer in your next question to avoid unnecessary confusion :) good luck and thanks